# How to replace the execution of a method with RhinoMocks

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, mocking, rhino-mocks

Can anyone please explain why in RhinoMocks this code still ends up executing the native `SomeVirtualMethod`?

```
var repository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyRepository>(null, null);
repository.Stub(x => x.SomeVirtualMethod()).Return(new List<SomeObject>());
```

When the second line runs, the original `SomeVirtualMethod` runs and crashes because it is out of context. I've also tried:

```
var repository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyRepository>(null, null);
repository.Stub(x => x.SomeVirtualMethod()).Do(new Func<List<SomeObject>>(() => new List<SomeObject>()));
```

How can I make sure only the substitute method is called?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your snippet and it works fine for me returning expected empty collection. The only reason I can imagine why your `SomeVirtualMethod` is still executed, because it is not actually virtual! Please, double check that again.

This is the code I tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Rhino.Mocks;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var stub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyRepository>(null,null);
            stub.Stub(x => x.SomeVirtualMethod()).Return(new List<SomeObject>());
            Assert.AreEqual(0, stub.SomeVirtualMethod().Count());
        }
    }

    public class MyRepository {

        public MyRepository(object a1, object a2) { }
        public virtual IEnumerable<SomeObject> SomeVirtualMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class SomeObject {}
}
```